# How to add tabs in CarPlay for Audio App?

Tags: carplay

I am working on my current iPhone audio app to be supported in CarPlay. But I am not able to show multiple tabs.

Answer (score 3):

To specify that you want tabs, you have to edit the plist of your app, adding the key `UIBrowsableContentSupportsSectionedBrowsing`:

```
<key>UIBrowsableContentSupportsSectionedBrowsing</key>
<true/>
```

The first layer of indices / items you return via the `MPPlayableItemsDataSource` will then be interpreted as source indices / items for tabs, as opposed to items on the top level.

Comment: @ossamacpp Yes, no problems with that. Setting an instance of `MPMediaItemArtwork` to `MPMediaItem.artwork` worked here as expected.

Comment: If you find this question to be answered, please remember to tick the 'question answered' button.